# Does Soul Harvest "Siphon" steal life?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

Is the Life the Witch Doctor gains from the "Siphon" rune of Soul Harvest taken from the enemy? Does the enemy's life decrease? Or does the Witch Doctor just gain the Life, without the monster losing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not do damage.  Note the text simply says:

> Gain 2171 Life for every enemy harvested.

No where does it actually do damage.  Just to be sure, I took my level 60 WD to a normal game and performed it and confirmed that no monsters died/took damage.